# Retrieving a Struct from MSMQ and convert it back to struct format in C++

Tags: c++, msmq

I have pushed a custom struct into MSMQ using MQSendMessage API and also I am successfully able to retrieve the message from the queue using MQReceiveMessage API. But the information is available in buffer of type UCHAR *(unsigned char *). 
I want to convert back the buffer to struct format and read the values. Any suggestion on how to do it??

Answer (score 0):

Specifically designed for such scenarios
[ProtBuff](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) This is serialization and pretty useful for sending information over the network

Comment: Thanks!! It looks like Protocol buffer is mainly used for serialized messages. But my requirement is to push Serialized data as well as File with huge size. Also I need to persist the data locally to make sure even if the Receiver machine is down, I can still get my data without any loss.